# Unable to Change Icon on Click()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this HTML

```
<li><button class="btn-link glyphicon @(I._tp_favourite == 0 ? "glyphicon-heart-empty" : "glyphicon-heart")" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="Fav(@I._id, @I._tp_favourite)" id="FavButton"></button></li>
```

OnClick I trigger this function

```
 function Fav(id,fav) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("_Fav", "my")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: id,
                fav: fav
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#FavButton').toggleClass('btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) { // Http Status is not 200
                alert(jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
    };
```

This should change the button class to `btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove` But it is not, Do i need to attach an ID with each `id="FavButton"`

Any Ideas

Cheers

Comment: Are you rendering this button inside a loop ?

Comment: Hi Yes, and i figured out, i needed to attach the ID with of the item with each item in the loop `id="FavButton_@I._id"` and then do the following in my function on Success `$('#FavButton_' + id).removeClass('btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty').addClass('btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-removet');`

Comment: yes. Id's has to be unique. Your code in OP will generate duplicate Ids. Another option is to use unobtrusive javascript and  `$(this)` to get access to the button which was clicked,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, I needed to attach the ID with each of in my loop

`id="FavButton_@I._id"`

and then do the following in my function on Success

```
 $('#FavButton_' + id).removeClass('btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty').addClass('btn-link glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
```

Comment: Far better to get rid of `onclick` and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - then its just `$(''button').click(function() {` and `$(this)` refers to the current element